# stored procedure parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I pass these two value combination separated by AND/ as parameter value to stored procedure:

```
"8033301552*" OR "08033301552*"
```

or

```
"Taiwo*" AND "Ayedun*"
```

I mean do I need to create a string and pass it as parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Officially not supported.

A workaround can be found at

[http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.sqlserver.reportingsvcs/browse_thread/thread/a5e0fdb24323aa13/e0fcc4c2d38883ec%23e0fcc4c2d38883ec?pli=1](http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.sqlserver.reportingsvcs/browse_thread/thread/a5e0fdb24323aa13/e0fcc4c2d38883ec#e0fcc4c2d38883ec?pli=1)

What doesn't work has nothing really to do with RS but has to do with Stored 
Procedures in SQL Server. You cannot do the following in a stored procedure. 
Let's say you have a Parameter called @MyParams 
Now you can map that parameter to a multi-value parameter but if in your 
stored procedure you try to do this: 
select * from sometable where somefield in (@MyParams) 
It won't work. Try it. Create a stored procedure and try to pass a 
multi-value parameter to the stored procedure. It won't work. 
What you can do is to have a string parameter that is passed as a multivalue 
parameter and then change the string into a table. 
This technique was told to me by SQL Server MVP, Erland Sommarskog 
For example I have done this 
inner join charlist_to_table(@STO,Default)f on b.sto = f.str 
So note this is NOT an issue with RS, it is strictly a stored procedure 
issue. 
Here is the function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION charlist_to_table 
                    (@list      ntext, 
                     @delimiter nchar(1) = N',') 
         RETURNS @tbl TABLE (listpos int IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL, 
                             str     varchar(4000), 
                             nstr    nvarchar(2000)) AS 
   BEGIN 
      DECLARE @pos      int, 
              @textpos  int, 
              @chunklen smallint, 
              @tmpstr   nvarchar(4000), 
              @leftover nvarchar(4000), 
              @tmpval   nvarchar(4000) 
      SET @textpos = 1 
      SET @leftover = '' 
      WHILE @textpos <= datalength(@list) / 2 
      BEGIN 
         SET @chunklen = 4000 - datalength(@leftover) / 2 
         SET @tmpstr = @leftover + substring(@list, @textpos, @chunklen) 
         SET @textpos = @textpos + @chunklen 
         SET @pos = charindex(@delimiter, @tmpstr) 
         WHILE @pos > 0 
         BEGIN 
            SET @tmpval = ltrim(rtrim(left(@tmpstr, @pos - 1))) 
            INSERT @tbl (str, nstr) VALUES(@tmpval, @tmpval) 
            SET @tmpstr = substring(@tmpstr, @pos + 1, len(@tmpstr)) 
            SET @pos = charindex(@delimiter, @tmpstr) 
         END 
         SET @leftover = @tmpstr 
      END 
      INSERT @tbl(str, nstr) VALUES (ltrim(rtrim(@leftover)), 
ltrim(rtrim(@leftover))) 
   RETURN 
   END 
GO
```

-- 
Bruce Loehle-Conger 
MVP SQL Server Reporting Services 
"Roland Müller"  wrote in message

Comment: Could you post the gist of the workaround. The link requires me to logon with a Google Account.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass arrays of values into a stored proc using XML data. I've found this to be a workable solution and solves issues of dynamic SQL possibly being affected by SQL injection.

Take a look at [this link](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html#XMLlist%20of%20values) for a basic example of how to do it. As the author suggests, this may be overkill for some solutions, but I think it is quite neat and could be modified to meet your requirements.